# Insert into table field a result of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

maybe this question is duplicate or my query in Google wasn't right, but I have a problem)
I have a 3 tables:
1. Contact (int ID, nvarchar Name)
2. City (int ID, nvarchar Name, int ContCount)
3. Adress (int ID, int CityID, int ContactID, int Year)

ContCount field - its a number of a Contacts what are living in some City (City.Name). My query for it:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Adresses WHERE dbo.Adresses.City_ID = 1`

Here is my question: I need to my ContCount field assign a result of this query. Can you help me? How can I do it?

P.S. Sorry for my English=)

Comment: Are you trying to `update` the `ContCount` for all cities in the City table? Or do you just want the `ContCount` for a particular `City_ID`?

Comment: It should be updating dynamicaly for all cities after updating,inserting etc. in Adress table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TSQL you can use the following code to save that variable:

```
DECLARE @ContCount as INT
SET @ContCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Adresses WHERE dbo.Adresses.City_ID = 1)
```

Im not quite sure what you want to do next, but you can use it in any query you write next, for example:

```
DECLARE @ContCount as INT
SET @ContCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Adresses WHERE dbo.Adresses.City_ID = 1)
UPDATE City SET ContCount=@ContCount Where ID=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've used such code:
UPDATE DBO.Cities
SET ContactCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Adresses WHERE dbo.Adresses.City_ID = dbo.Cities.ID)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could combine into a single statement. I've never used a CROSS APPLY in an UPDATE statement, but it ought to work:

```
UPDATE c SET ContCount = b.AddressCount
FROM dbo.City c 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(1) as AddressCount
             FROM dbo.Address a 
             WHERE a.City_ID = c.City_ID) b
```

(optional: `WHERE c.City_ID = 1`)